# How do I write the media query correctly to use one stylesheet in IE and another in all other browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I write the media query correctly to use one stylesheet in IE and another in all other browsers? I"m experimenting with media queries and IE detection seems to work just fine for @media screen like in this example:

```css
@media screen{

.myDiv{
color:green;
}

}

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {

.myDiv{
color:purple;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
This should be purple in ie.
</div>
```

However, when I try to write the equivalent @media print query the results immediately get put onto the screen like so:

```css
@media screen{

.myDiv{
color:green;
}

}

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {

.myDiv{
color:purple;
}

}


@media print{

.myDiv{
color:black;
}

}

@media print and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {

.myDiv{
color: red;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
This should be purple on an ie screen and red when printed from ie. In chrome the text should be green on the screen and black when printed.
</div>
```

How do I write the media query correctly to use one stylesheet in IE and another in all other browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use multiple conditions you should use `and` or `or` between then:

```
@media print and (-ms-high-contrast: active) and (-ms-high-contrast: none)
```

```css
@media screen{

.myDiv{
color:green;
}

}

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active) and (-ms-high-contrast: none) {

.myDiv{
color:purple;
}

}


@media print{

.myDiv{
color:black;
}

}

@media print and (-ms-high-contrast: active) and (-ms-high-contrast: none) {

.myDiv{
color: red;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
This should be purple on an ie screen and red when printed from ie. In chrome the text should be green on the screen and black when printed.
</div>
```